# How to generate a CSV file for a loop output data?

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv

I have an API that generates the following output:

This is a dataframe 'Fruits_Color'

```
    Fruits   Color
 0  Apple    Red
    Fruits   Color
 0  Banana   Yellow
    Fruits   Color
 0  Grapes   Black
```

How can I generate CSV which looks like the following (desired output):

```
    Fruits   Color
    Apple    Red 
    Banana   Yellow
    Grapes   Black
```

I've tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Fruits_Color)
print(df)
df.to_csv('Fruits.csv', index = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
    Fruits   Color
 0  Apple    Red
```

Should I use for-loop or is there any other method?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like these are three separate dataframes, since the columns are shown 3 times and you have 3x index 0. Could that be the case? If so, you could first concat the dataframes before exporting to csv.

Comment: Yes, These are 3 different dataframes, I guess I need to combine first right? But what if I have 100's of dataframes?

Comment: Depends on how the API provides the dataframes. Do they come in batches, is it one dataframe a time?

Comment: It is one dataframe at a time from the API, I have over 120 small dataframes currently generated.

Comment: I've updated my answer and made an example with a for loop.

Comment: Why do you create dataframes from API response? What is the API response - JSON? Why not loop (assuming you only get a single item response) and just write to CSV? What does it mean you have 120 dtaframes generated - do you store them somehow?

Comment: API response is JSON. I have used loop in the API so it generates one dataframe at a time. I'm doing CSV because we need our output in CSV format. The output I get looks similar to first block code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To simulate the API I made three dataframes and used a for loop. I've used df1, df2 and df3 as example names since the name of your dataframes is not given in the description. Make sure you declare export_df before the API, then at the first API result coming in you set the export_df to that dataframe. All other dataframes that come afterwards can be concatenated to the first dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruits':['Apple'],
    'Colors':['Red']
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruits':['Banana'],
    'Colors':['Yellow']
    })

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruits':['Grapes'],
    'Colors':['Black']
    })

frames = [df1,df2,df3]

export_df = None
for df in frames:
    if export_df is None:
        export_df = df1
    else:
        export_df = export_df.append(df,ignore_index=True)


export_df = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index=True)
export_df.to_csv('Fruits.csv', index = False)
```